# js loop work in console, but not update in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this loop not work?

```
function progress_metro(from, to)
{
    console.log(from+" "+to);
    for(var i = from; i <= to; i++)
    {
        console.log("asdasdasd - "+i+" "+from+" "+to);
        setTimeout(function() {$(".percentage").text(i+"%")},i+100);
    }
}
```

Console log is

```
asdasdasd - 26 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 27 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 28 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 29 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 30 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 31 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 32 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 33 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 34 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 35 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 36 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 37 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 38 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 39 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 40 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 41 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 42 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 43 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 44 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 45 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 46 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 47 26 50 viewCountry.php?country=albania:110
asdasdasd - 48 26 50
```

Thanks!

P.S. Thanks you all, guys! I love this comunity!
[Problem](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop/)
jsfiddle - good thing, thanks for share

Comment: a jsfiddle would be better.

Comment: tell me the from and to values

Comment: setTimeout(function() {"$('.percentage').text(i+'%')}",i+100);

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v64Kd/

Comment: i am do metro style progress bar, background changes colors and below white color text. So, i need update .percentage

Comment: shadow, this is not help, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you [want this JsFiddle Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/v64Kd/3/)

Due to closure effect in loop value of i gets updated and you see only last, and time in settimeout is in millisecond, 100 ms is too quick to see response.

```
function progress_metro(from, to) {
    console.log(from + " " + to);
    for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {

        console.log("asdasdasd - " + i + " " + from + " " + to);
         doSetTimeout(i);
    }
}
function doSetTimeout(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {setDom(i)}, i*100);
}

function setDom(i) {        
    $(".percentage").text(i + "%");
}
progress_metro(5, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Very probably because the dom wasn't ready, but it's already ready when opening the console. You should have:

```
function progress_metro(from, to)
{
    ...
}

$(function(){  //Start calling when document is ready
   progress_metro(...);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Now this is calling when document is ready

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think the for loop overwrites the previous written values as soon as it executes. I worked a turnaround here.

I have pushed all the values into an array and then looped through it create a feature somewhat similar to what you will like .

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/v64Kd/1/)**

I am also including the code for your reference.

```
var arr=[];
function progress_metro(from, to)
{
     console.log(from+" "+to);
     for(var i = from; i <= to; i++)
     {
         arr.push(i);
     }
        var j = 0;
        setInterval(function() { 
          console.log("asdasdasd - "+j+" "+from+" "+to);
          $(".percentage").text(arr[j++]+"%")},1000);
}
progress_metro(5,100);
```

Edit it as per your requirement.

hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

```
here is the lastest code with some tweaks 


from=1000,to=1100; // dummy value say value 
function progress_metro(from, to,i){
    console.log("asdasdasd - "+i+" "+from+" "+to);
    setInterval(function() {
    $(".percentage").append(i+"%"+"<br>");
    },1);
 }
for(var i = from; i <= to; i++){
progress_metro(from,to,i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T4GgQ/

& please next time make sure you include fiddle    :) coz its hard to understand wat u want

Answer (score 1):

Here's one suggestion try writing function outside the loop:

```
function progress_metro(from, to) {
    console.log(from+" "+to);
    for(var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        console.log("asdasdasd - "+i+" "+from+" "+to);
        setTimeout(print(i), i+100);
    }
}

function print(i) {
    $(".percentage").append(i+"% <br/>");
}

progress_metro(0,100);
```